# Execution failed for task ':share:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using `share: ^0.6.4+3` in my project but when I launch my project on my emulator, I am encountering:

```
Execution failed for task ':share:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/chinkysight/Desktop/Pecha/build/share/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/debug/annotationProcessors.json (No such file or directory)
```

I tried downgrading the version, but it wasn't helpful :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/chinkysight/Desktop/Pecha/build/share/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/debug/annotationProcessors.json (No such file or directory)`

you can delete your `.gradle` folder and rebuild project again or you can update your gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

change the value of the gradle version to the latest version

Comment: My gradle is already update : **#Thu May 21 10:32:47 NPT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip**

Comment: I again updated the gradle and its working now :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting the **android/.gradle, android/build, android/app/build**. This is the only thing that worked for me.
2. Then open **Android Studio -> File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart**